# Error handling on a Foreach-Object

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I want to do something like:

```
Get-ChildItem "somepath" | where {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{
    #do something if Get-ChildItem didn't receive an error
    #else do something else if did get an error
}
```

How do I go about this?

EDIT:
I currently have this:

```
Get-ChildItem $somelongpath -Recurse -ErrorVariable MyError -ErrorAction Stop  | where {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{
     if($MyError){
        Write-Host "Don't do it"
     } else {
        Write-Host "Yay!"
     }
}
```

Say that $somelongpath is a path that exceeds the 260 limit and therefore get-childitem should receive an error and print "Don't do it". But it doesn't... What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `-ErrorAction` and `-ErrorVariable`. It seems that using -Recurse in this way just ignores the directory with the error so I wrote a little recursive function instead.

```
gci -Attributes Directory | Foreach {
    foo $_.FullName
}

function foo
{
    Param ([string] $currentPath)

    Write-Host "Getting subdirectories of" $currentPath

    $result = gci $currentPath -Attributes Directory -ErrorVariable HasError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($HasError) { 
        Write-Host "error" $HasError
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "ok"    
    }

    if($result) {
        $result | Foreach {
            foo $_.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/09/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now it is no longer a ForeachLoop. I want to check each item if an error occured or not and do something accordingly.

Comment: @BenjaminS.Sorterup you are of course right. I've had another stab at it

Comment: @ChristianHagelind Once again thank you. Seems closer to what I need, how do I make that recursive?

Comment: well it is recursive now. foo calls itself from inside the function

Comment: @ChrisHagelid Oh right, I didn't see! I'll play around with this, thank you!